# Jenkins build with parameters only calls master branch

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am building a gitlab/jenkins stack, and have connected my gitlab to jenkins. Now when I want to build my test item with a parameter rather than "master", Jenkins only uses "master" branch to build and test. What am I missing? My Jenkins version is 2.150 (latest LTE) and all of the plugins are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem:

There is an option in {Your_Project_Name} > Configure > Source Code Management > Branches to Build
It was set to "master", I deleted it and then I implemented the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108380/jenkins-how-to-build-a-specific-branch) as the accepted answer, and then it worked.